# groupby ngFor angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngfor, angular-pipe

Good day, i've been trying to display an array by groups title, i get my array from a webservice and i want to display the item by groups title

example

Group1
item 1
item 2
item 3

Group2
item 1
item 2
item 3

[image]

here is my array

```
                [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "Item 1",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "title": "Communication"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "title": "Item 2",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "title": "Communication"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "title": "Item 1",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "title": "Creativie Art"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "title": "Item 3",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "2",
                            "title": "Communication"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "title": "Item 2",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "title": "Creativie Art"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "title": "Item 3",
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "id": "1",
                            "title": "Creativie Art"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

i cant paste all the array data because its too long but this is the array structure

Comment: i understand that Object.assign({}, ...value['groups']); can convert the groups node to an object but i dont know if this helps

Comment: please share actual array so that we can help you.

Comment: i've written the actual in the question, its same as the sample array. no difference

Comment: So where are other items 2 and 3?

Comment: i've updated the array but cant paste all due to its length but the array structure remains the same. it currently has 2 groups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one option of how we can do it:

**app.component.ts**

```typescript
const groupsDict = this.arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  cur.groups.forEach(({ id, title}) => {
    acc[id] = acc[id] || { id, title };
    acc[id].items = acc[id].items || [];
    acc[id].items.push({ id: cur.id, title: cur.title });
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
this.groups = Object.keys(groupsDict).map(x => groupsDict[x]);
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div *ngFor="let group of groups" class="col">
    <h2>{{ group.title }}</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let item of group.items">
      {{ item.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3kuj8?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**