# How do i make use of groupingby in java

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, java-stream

I have a movie list from a web service that i need to group using genres attribute from the data. My question is very similar to this [groupby ngFor angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714333/groupby-ngfor-angular2) but in **java** instead.

movie list from the web service looks like this

```
[
    {
        "title": "AAAAAAAA",
        "genres": [
          "Comedy"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "BBBBBBBBBBBB",
        "genres": [
          "Action", "Adventure"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "CCCCCCCCCCCCC",
        "genres": [
          "Action"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "DDDDDDDDDDDD",
        "genres": [
          "Comedy", "Adventure"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE",
        "genres": [
          "Horror"
        ]
    }
]
```

here is what i'm trying to achieve but i cant seems to get it right

```
[
    {
        "Action": [
            {
                "title": "BBBBBBBBBBBB",
                "genres": [
                  "Action", "Adventure"
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "CCCCCCCCCCCCC",
                "genres": [
                  "Action"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Adventure": [
            {
                "title": "BBBBBBBBBBBB",
                "genres": [
                  "Action", "Adventure"
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "DDDDDDDDDDDD",
                "genres": [
                  "Comedy", "Adventure"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Comedy": [
            {
                "title": "AAAAAAAA",
                "genres": [
                  "Comedy"
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "DDDDDDDDDDDD",
                "genres": [
                  "Comedy", "Adventure"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "Horror": [
            {
                "title": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE",
                "genres": [
                  "Horror"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

i've tried replicating the javascript solution from the answer in
[groupby ngFor angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47714333/groupby-ngfor-angular2) but I'm stucked

```
    ItemArray.stream().reduce((identity, accumulator) -> {    
        accumulator.getGenres().forEach((k) -> {});
        return identity;
    });
```

Comment: Try doing it with a standard for-loop first. Whenever I'm struggling with how to construct a stream, having the imperative version helps a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be easier not to use streams:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByGenre = new HashMap<>();
for (Item item : items) {
  for (String genre : item.genres()) {
    itemsByGenre.computeIfAbsent(genre, g -> new ArrayList<>()).add(item);
  }
}
```

The key point here is that you need to explode by genre, because each item can be in multiple genres. So, you could do something like this:

```
Map<String, List<Item>> itemsByGentre = items.stream()
    // Make a stream of map entries where the key is the genre, and the value is the item.
    .flatMap(i -> i.genres().stream().map(g -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(g, i))
    .collect(
        // Now, group by key (genre)...
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            // and map the entry to just the value (the item),
            // and collect the items into a list.
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```